# How do you set a session variable to tell Devise where to redirect after Sign In or Sign Up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Does devise have a method built in that you can pass a variable which contains a URL to redirect the user to after they sign in or sign up?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out

Answer (score 1):

If your model is called `User`, then define a `user_root` route in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
match '/profile', :to => "user#profile", :as => "user_root"
```

Devise will then automatically redirect the user to this path.

There's a page in the Wiki that explains this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out.

Answer (score 0):

application_controller.rb

```
...
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    example_path
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    example_path
  end
...
```